# How do I send PASS reports to CPAN Testers from CPANPLUS?

Tags: perl, automated-tests, cpan

CPANPLUS has a plugin to report failures to CPAN Testers. However it doesn't report passes, only failures. How do I report passes for some modules I'm interested in?

Ideally I'd like to have an ability to smoke some modules from a predefined whitelist whenever a new versions of them are available. I don't want to constantly monitor the new versions, as I don't have a constantly running box, but I'd like to regularly test the modules I'm interested in.

Ideally I'd like to do that from `cpanp` because it does other things for me, such as finding outdated modules and building various binary packages of modules before installing them. So if it's some other tool than cpanp, I'd like to avoid the need to install the modules in the process. In case it's needed I can install the dependencies using cpanp and then run the tests using other tools.

Comment: Are you setting the [cpantest](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPANPLUS::Config#cpantest) option? It doesn't specify whether it will report pass or fail, it seems like an oversight if it only reports fails.

Comment: There is https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus::reporter for `cpanm`. Is there a similar one for `cpanp` maybe?

Comment: @Grinnz Yes, I have cpantest option set. It's not an oversight to have pass reports disabled by default. Most people use cpanp on every deployment, as opposed to building packages.So the desision not to send passes avoids flooding of cpantesters which has limited capacity.

Comment: It seems unfortunate, PASS reports are just as important to determine the cause of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

So far the best solution I've found is to use https://metacpan.org/pod/CPANPLUS::YACSmoke. It lets me test individual distributions specified on the command line while avoiding retesting the same version over and over.